# What is this area on a lens seen from extreme angle?

Tags: optics, lenses

This has been a secret to me since childhood: a normal lens made of glass in front of a white LCD screen (shot with a crappy phone camera)...

[image: nothing special, just a lens in front of an LCD monitor and 2 tungsten lamps reflected in it]

...if viewed from an extreme angle shows a very distorted something of a greenish color

[image: now this is interesting: although the screen is white, you can see green through the lens]

([full res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miObc.jpg))

My guess it that at this angle the glass starts refracting, producing sort of a mirror corridor effect, adding the green tint of the glass' own color. I never figured out the light ray path within it.

What exactly happens with the light?

Comment: Imgur is blocked at my work site, so going on guess: cheap glass is in fact green.  It's just not noticeable until you get a relatively thick piece.  Tilting the lens presents a "thick" path to your eyeball.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft imgur is blocked at your work and you haven't solved that problem yet? Must be a very interesting/important work.

Comment: Still, I'd like to know how exactly how I can see that part from the other side, which isn't even the rim.

Comment: Do you know whether or not the lens is coated (e.g. anti-reflective coating)? If the surface is coated, you will see colors under different viewing angles, because the thin coating acts as a reflective interference filter.

Comment: I've seen the same green when looking at sheets of glass from their sides.

Comment: @Jitter oh, you're right!

Comment: Jitter is right. When you look at blocks of different optical glasses, sometimes you see faint casts and hues other than green, but mostly they are very clear (chalcogenide glasses are often noticeably brown). Window glass is never thick, so a faint cast does not matter. So this is your answer: the low-cost makeup of glass in everyday windows or other low cost components makes it green.

Comment: So I guessed right where the color comes from, but the question was different.